# configure/customize an AVD

Tags: android, target, configure, customization, android-virtual-device

In the AVD manager for Android in ubuntu I can specify the size of the SD card storage, the "skin", the screen resolution, and certain hardware specs.

But what if I wanted to make something like a new android ROM image or build to use rahter than the given or coming options in target, is that possible.

Is there a step-by-step document describing how to configure/customize an AVD to that level of detail?

Thanks in advance.
kash

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code. Make you customizations. Build it. Run the custom OS on your emulator.

http://source.android.com/source/index.html